# QueryOver multiple tables with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, dto, queryover

I'm trying to left join multiple tables and project some columns that result from this join onto a new entity, and then taking a few records from this result from my database. I've taken a look on a few similar questions here on SF, but I'm not managing to assemble all of those parts into a piece of code that works.

Here is the query I'm trying to generate with NHibernate:

```
select * from 
( select LOC_Key.KeyName, LOC_Translation.TranslationString, LOC_Translation.Comments
  from LOC_Key
  left join LOC_Translation
  on LOC_Key.ID = LOC_Translation.KeyID and LOC_Translation.LanguageID = 6
  order by LOC_Key.KeyName 
) as keyTable 
limit 0,100
```

I have three entities here, Key, Translation and Language. A Key is a unique string identifier for different translations of a same word in different languages. I want to show the first n keys in alphabetical order for a language, but I want all keys listed, not only the ones that are translated (that's why I'm using a left join).

I took a look at `QueryOver<>`, `Select()` method and `List<object[]>()` method but I can't even manage to have a code that compiles in the first place.

I could use C# linq after getting all records from the tables Key and Translation, having something like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> k = RepositoryKey.GetLimits( offset, size ).Select( x => x.KeyName );

IEnumerable<TranslationDescriptor> t = RepositoryTranslation.GetAllWhere( x => x.LanguageID.LanguageCode == language && k.Contains ( x.KeyID.KeyName ) ).ToList().ConvertAll( new Converter<Translation, TranslationDescriptor>( ( x ) => { return new TranslationDescriptor { LanguageCode = x.LanguageID.LanguageCode, KeyName = x.KeyID.KeyName, Comments = x.Comments, TranslationString = x.TranslationString }; } ) );

var q = from key in k
        join trl in t on key equals trl.KeyName into temp
        from tr in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new TranslationDescriptor { KeyName = key, LanguageCode = language, Comments = ( tr == null ) ? string.Empty : tr.Comments, TranslationString = ( tr == null ) ? string.Empty : tr.TranslationString };
```

However, that's very slow. By the way, my implementation for GetLimits and GetAllWhere is:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAllWhere(Func<T, bool> func)
{
    var products = Session.Query<T>().Where(func);
    return products;
}

public IEnumerable<T> GetLimits(int offset, int size)
{
    return Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).SetFirstResult(offset).SetMaxResults(size).List<T>();
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Bruno

Comment: without reproduceable code (meaning including mappings/entities you have) etc it is pretty hard to give you an answer. But in general, your SQL Query example contains a nested select within the from clause. This is not supported by nhibernate... Maybe that is what is hindering you to get it running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing a little bit at your entities and mappings, but the following might help you get ideas.  It joins `Key` to `Translation` with a left outer join, then projects the results to a new DTO object.

```
[Test]
public void LeftOuterProjection()
{
    using (var s = OpenSession())
    using (var t = s.BeginTransaction())
    {
        // Set up aliases to use in the queryover.
        KeyDTO dtoAlias = null;
        Key keyAlias = null;
        Translation translationAlias = null;

        var results = s.QueryOver<Key>(() => keyAlias)
            .JoinAlias(k => k.Translations, () => translationAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
            .Where(() => translationAlias.LanguageId == 6)
            .OrderBy(() => keyAlias.KeyName).Asc
            .Select(Projections.Property(() => keyAlias.KeyName).WithAlias(() => dtoAlias.KeyName),
                    Projections.Property(() => translationAlias.TranslationString).WithAlias(() => dtoAlias.TranslationString),
                    Projections.Property(() => translationAlias.Comments).WithAlias(() => dtoAlias.Comments))
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<KeyDTO>())
            .List<KeyDTO>();
    }
}

public class KeyDTO
{
    public string KeyName { get; set; }
    public string TranslationString { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Key
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string KeyName { get; set; }
    public IList<Translation> Translations { get; set; }
}

public class Translation
{
    public Key Key { get; set; }
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public string TranslationString { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot. The mapping you came with is very similar to what I already had. I did not had the IList<Translation> on the Key entity, which I needed to create in order to make the query work (it was just an one-to-many missing mapping on that entity). I slightly modified the code to take the limits and to make the Where restriction in the Join clause, not after the join operation.

Answer (score 0):

The modifications I made to my code following ngm suggestion (thanks!):

```
Language l = RepositoryLanguage.GetSingleOrDefault(x => x.LanguageCode
== language); 

KeyTranslationDTO dtoAlias = null;  
Key keyAlias = null;  
Translation translationAlias = null; 

var results = RepositoryKey.GetSession()
  .QueryOver<Key>(() => keyAlias)
  .OrderBy(() => keyAlias.KeyName).Asc
  .JoinQueryOver<Translation>( k => k.Translations, () => translationAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin, Restrictions.Where( () => translationAlias.LanguageID == l ) )   
  .Select(Projections.Property(() => keyAlias.KeyName).WithAlias(() => dtoAlias.KeyName),  
          Projections.Property(() => translationAlias.TranslationString).WithAlias(() => dtoAlias.TranslationString),    
          Projections.Property(() => translationAlias.Comments).WithAlias(() => dtoAlias.Comments))
  .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<KeyTranslationDTO>())
  .Skip(index).Take(amount)
  .List<KeyTranslationDTO>();
```